# TypeScript: is there a way to achieve something like prop spreading with Generics?

Tags: typescript

I have a interface `Foo`

```
interface Foo<T, K, U> {
  // omit implementation details
}
```

It takes 3 generic params... so whenever I need to use this interface I need to explictly pass 3 types to its generic interface. I wonder if there is a way define a new type to group 3 types and we pass that one grouped type to this generic so it takes that one type instead of 3 types to its generic interface. Or maybe we spread out the type so it fills out the 3 slots for the generic interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
interface Foo<T extends { first: any, second: any, third: any }> {
  property1: T['first']
  property2: T['second']
  property3: T['third']
}

const bar: Foo<{ 
  first: string, 
  second: number, 
  third: boolean 
}> = {
  property1: 'a',
  property2: 1,
  property3: true
}
```

Or use tuples:

```
interface Foo<T extends [any, any, any]> {
  property1: T[0]
  property2: T[1]
  property3: T[2]
}

const bar: Foo<[string, number, boolean]> = {
  property1: 'a',
  property2: 1,
  property3: true
}
```